# Setting up auto replies in Lotus Notes bassed on a specific subject

Tags: lotus-notes

How do I set up an auto-reply in Lotus Notes based on the text in the subject field?  Would it be possible to set up the auto-responder to reply to the email address in the cc: field and not just the sender?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use an agent to do this. You can find tons of resources by googling "auto-reply agent lotus notes" but it's highly likely that the administrators at your company will disable it or have already prevented your ability to create agents. Auto responding agents are especially problematic since they tend to be the root cause of email loops.

If you have a legit business need for auto responding, you may want to work with your admins, they may already have a group inbox style mailfile design setup for auto replying.